# Distributed Availability Groups refusing to resync my FILESTREAM database with SUSPEND_FROM_CAPTURE

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups, sql-server-2022

My home lab setup consists of four servers running in HyperV across two physical hosts.  The SQL Server instances are SQLAG101, SQLAG102, SQLAG201, and SQLAG202.

SQLAG101 and SQLAG102 are members of the SQLAG100 Availability Group, and are on the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

SQLAG201 and SQLAG202 are members of the SQLAG200 Availability Group, and are on the 192.168.2.0/24 network.

Traffic is routed between the two subnets, which are both local to my lab (i.e. there is very little latency involved).

SQLDAG is a Distributed Availability Group spanning SQLAG100 and SQLAG200.  This has been running well for about 6 months, with automatic failover between the AG member servers, and manual failovers between the two AGs working correctly, and without data loss.

On my test server, I'm seeing the following errors on my Distributed AG Forwarder for a database using `FILESTREAM`:

> The operating system returned the error '2(The system cannot find the file specified.)' while attempting 'CreateFileW' on 'F:\SQLServer\HV2019\FILESTREAM\dag_test_db\dag_test_db_fg_fs_f01\3e6a0757-7405-4ee2-b8a8-df878b8cd7ce\a10e3ae8-922c-4821-904e-7555c031630d\0000008f-000292b0-0006' at 'fsdohdlr.cpp'(2474).

> Always On Availability Groups data movement for database 'dag_test_db' has been suspended for the following reason: "system" (Source ID 3; Source string: 'SUSPEND_FROM_CAPTURE'). To resume data movement on the database, you will need to resume the database manually. For information about how to resume an availability database, see SQL Server Books Online.

<sup>*(love that Books Online reference, btw)*</sup>

To troubleshoot, I've completely dropped the `dag_test_db` from the forwarder and the forwarders secondary.  I then took a full backup from the primary, and restored it to the forwarder, and rolled forward by restoring log backups as necessary prior to adding the `dag_test_db` back into the forwarders Availability Group via `ALTER DATABASE [dag_test_db] SET HADR AVAILABILITY GROUP = SQLAG200;`

Initially, the Availability Group Dashboard for the forwarders AG (SQLAG200) showed the database as being synchronized, but after about an hour the sync state shows `NOT SYNCHRONIZING` and the sync health reason description shows `SUSPEND_FROM_CAPTURE`.

Running `chkdsk /f` on the F: drive reports no errors.

`dbcc checkdb (dag_test_db)` from the primary returns no errors.

I have written a query to read all the data from filestream; perhaps that will show something interesting.  Once I have the results from that test, I'll update the question.  The query is using `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` via sqlcmd.exe to connect to the forwarder instance.  This is the query, for those interested:

```
USE [dag_test_db];
GO
DECLARE @d varbinary(max);
DECLARE @f nvarchar(260);
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT
      [f].[file_data]
    , [f].[original_file_name]
FROM [dbo].[files] [f];

OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @d, @f;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @f + N': ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(11), LEN(@d), 0);
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @d, @f;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Perhaps some dashing young Microsoft engineer can help me understand what is causing an error in `fsdohdlr.cpp at 2474`?

`DBCC CHECKDB ([dag_test_db]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;` on the global primary shows no corruption.

Converting the file name in the error message to a decimal LSN, and using `fn_dblog` on the global primary to display the contents of the log shows:

| Current LSN | Operation | Context | Transaction ID | LogBlockGeneration | Tag Bits | Log Record Fixed Length | Log Record Length | Previous LSN | Flag Bits | Log Reserve | AllocUnitId | AllocUnitName | Page ID | Slot ID | Previous Page LSN | PartitionId | RowFlags | Num Elements | Offset in Row | Modify Size | Checkpoint Begin | CHKPT Begin DB Version | Max XDESID | Num Transactions | Checkpoint End | CHKPT End DB Version | Minimum LSN | Dirty Pages | Oldest Replicated Begin LSN | Next Replicated End LSN | Last Distributed Backup End LSN | Last Distributed End LSN | Repl Min Hold LSN | Server UID | SPID | Beginlog Status | Xact Type | Begin Time | Transaction Name | Transaction SID | Parent Transaction ID | Oldest Active Transaction ID | Xact ID | Xact Node ID | Xact Node Local ID | End AGE | End Time | Transaction Begin | Replicated Records | Oldest Active LSN | Server Name | Database Name | Mark Name | Master XDESID | Master DBID | Preplog Begin LSN | Prepare Time | Virtual Clock | Previous Savepoint | Savepoint Name | Rowbits First Bit | Rowbits Bit Count | Rowbits Bit Value | Number of Locks | Lock Information | LSN before writes | Pages Written | Command Type | Publication ID | Article ID | Partial Status | Command | Byte Offset | New Value | Old Value | New Split Page | Rows Deleted | Bytes Freed | CI Table Id | CI Index Id | NewAllocUnitId | FileGroup ID | Meta Status | File Status | File ID | Physical Name | Logical Name | Format LSN | RowsetId | TextPtr | Column Offset | Flags | Text Size | Offset | Old Size | New Size | Description | Bulk allocated extent count | Bulk RowsetId | Bulk AllocUnitId | Bulk allocation first IAM Page ID | Bulk allocated extent ids | VLFs added | InvalidateCache Id | InvalidateCache keys | CopyVerionInfo Source Page Id | CopyVerionInfo Source Page LSN | CopyVerionInfo Source Slot Id | CopyVerionInfo Source Slot Count | RowLog Contents 0 | RowLog Contents 1 | RowLog Contents 2 | RowLog Contents 3 | RowLog Contents 4 | RowLog Contents 5 | Compression Log Type | Compression Info | PageFormat PageType | PageFormat PageFlags | PageFormat PageLevel | PageFormat PageStat | PageFormat FormatOption | Log Record |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000008F:000292B0:0006 | LOP_FS_DOWNLEVEL_OP | LCX_NULL | 0000:0022f09f | 0 | 0x0000 | 24 | 360 | 0000008F:000292B0:0005 | 0x0002 | 366 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Operation CREATE;File Id 65537;Name 3e6a0757-7405-4ee2-b8a8-df878b8cd7ce\a10e3ae8-922c-4821-904e-7555c031630d\0000008f-000292b0-0006 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 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|

The file referenced in the error message does exist on the forwarder's filesystem:

```
C:\Users\Hannah>dir F:\SQLServer\HV2019\FILESTREAM\dag_test_db\dag_test_db_fg_fs_f01\3e6a0757-7405-4ee2-b8a8-df878b8cd7ce\a10e3ae8-922c-4821-904e-7555c031630d\0000008f-000292b0-0006
 Volume in drive F has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 90BA-CEC3

 Directory of F:\SQLServer\HV2019\FILESTREAM\dag_test_db\dag_test_db_fg_fs_f01\3e6a0757-7405-4ee2-b8a8-df878b8cd7ce\a10e3ae8-922c-4821-904e-7555c031630d

04/28/2023  10:27 PM           797,346 0000008f-000292b0-0006
               1 File(s)        797,346 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  123,663,937,536 bytes free
```

`icacls` for the path in question on the forwarder shows:

```
icacls F:\SQLServer\HV2019\FILESTREAM\dag_test_db\dag_test_db_fg_fs_f01\3e6a0757-7405-4ee2-b8a8-df878b8cd7ce\a10e3ae8-922c-4821-904e-7555c031630d
F:\SQLServer\HV2019\FILESTREAM\dag_test_db\dag_test_db_fg_fs_f01\3e6a0757-7405-4ee2-b8a8-df878b8cd7ce\a10e3ae8-922c-4821-904e-7555c031630d NT SERVICE\MSSQL$HV2019:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                                                                                                                                           OWNER RIGHTS:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                                                                                                                                           BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

The permissions look good from what I can see - the SQL Server service as full control on the file, and indeed the entire folder structure from `F:\SQLServer\HV2019`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145728/discussion-on-question-by-hannah-vernon-distributed-availability-groups-refusing)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to conclusively determine what the root cause of the `SUSPEND_FROM_CAPTURE` was.  Apparently this status indicates the forwarder (or secondary) can no longer read the log stream from the primary in a way that allows the secondary to keep up with the primary.

In order to resolve this at the forwarder, I removed the database from the SQLAG200 Availability Group primary (i.e. the Forwarder), then dropped it from the SQLAG200 Availability Group's secondary.  I then restored the database from backups on the SQLAG200 secondary, and the SQLAG200 primary ensuring applicable transaction log backups were restored to bring each copy of the database as close as possible to the state in the global primary copy of the database on SQLAG100.  Once the restores completed, I was able to get the forwarder caught up with the global primary by:

```
ALTER DATABASE [dag_test_db] SET HADR AVAILABILITY GROUP = [SQLAG200];
ALTER DATABASE [dag_test_db] SET HADR RESUME;
```

This associates the newly restored database to the forwarders Availability Group, and by extension, the global primarys Availability Group via the Distributed Availability Group.

Once the forwarder was on-board, I did the following on the forwarders secondary:

```
ALTER DATABASE [dag_test_db] SET HADR AVAILABILITY GROUP = [SQLAG200];
ALTER DATABASE [dag_test_db] SET HADR RESUME;
```

And finally, it seems stable.  The takeaway for me from all this was never at any point did the primary copy of the database go offline, or become unavailable for my C# Filestream test client.  It just kept on writing files into the `dag_test_db` filestream filegroup.  It might take a while, but as long as the primary is online, the business is not going to be too upset.

I'm glad to have a home lab setup like this where I can practice how to handle these kinds of issues before they affect a real production database.

Microsoft CSS has an undocumented Trace Flag that can be used at SQL Server startup to disable multiple log streams, which is a new feature in SQL Server 2022.  In my case, enabling that trace flag resolved the issue; removing the trace flag caused the issue to recur almost immediately.